# Update angularjs view when using "Controller as var" syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've a small site that has 3 views, and everytime i change the view, new data is loaded into it (Home, search sombody. Dashboard, a collection of data about them, detail, specific deatils about one item).

I am loading the data like such

```
<section id="recentSearches" class="frame" data-ng-controller="HomeCtrl as ctrl">
  <h1>Recently Searched</h1>
  <div data-ng-repeat="name in ctrl.recentSearches | reverse">
    <a class="name" href="/#/dashboard/{{name | formatSlug}}" data-ng-bind="name"></a>
  </div>
</section>
```

and just for reference, `recentSearches` is populated in the controller by a service (this is `HomeCtrl`) like such:

```
this.recentSearches = Services.recentSearches.data;
```

My problem is, every time i switch a view, it doesn't update the previous data in the view, when I reload the page though, it assigns the proper data in the view (recalling the data based on the permalink).

I assume this is happening because the data is not in `$scope`? When i had the data in scope it updated fine, but i am moving away from storing data in scope completely and this is my last hurtle.

Any help is greatly appreciated and let me know if you need any more info or code. Thanks!

**UPDATE**: One of my controllers, the other 2 are setup in the same way.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.Controller.Home', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
    pageTitle: 'Home'
  });
}])

.controller('HomeCtrl', ['Services', '$rootScope', 'RecentGames', 'Summoners', 'Champions', '$filter',
function(Services, $rootScope, RecentGames, Summoners, Champions, $filter) {
  this.slContainer = document.getElementById('summonerLookup');
  this.rsContainer = document.getElementById('recentSearches');
  this.recentSearches = Services.recentSearches.data;



  // Initalize
  // -----------------------
  this.init = function ( ) {
    Services.log('[init][controller] Home');

    // Focus on the form
    this.slContainer.querySelector('input[name=summonerName]').focus();

    // Register Event Listeners
    this.events();

    // Remove the loading overlay
    Services.removeLoading();
  };




  // Assign Events
  // -----------------------
  this.events = function ( ) {

    // The main form input submit
    this.slContainer.addEventListener('submit', this.summonerLookup);

    // The recent searches list
    this.rsContainer.addEventListener('click', this.loadRecentlySearched.bind(this));

  };




  // Submit the lookup form
  // -----------------------
  this.summonerLookup = function ( e, val ) {
    if(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    if(!val){
      val = $filter('formatSlug')(this.summonerName.value);
    }

    Summoners.getByName( val ).then(function success(results){ // Grab the summoner
      RecentGames.get().then(function success(results){ // Populate the summoners recent games
        RecentGames.data = results;
        Champions.getUsed();
      });
    });
  };




  // Load a recently searched profile
  // TODO: load recentsearched from the a tag being clicked, not this.
  // -----------------------
  this.loadRecentlySearched = function ( e ) {
    var el = e.target || e.toElement;
    var isButton = el.className.match(/name/g);

    // Block event if is not button
    if( isButton === null ) { return false; }

    // Get summoner information
    this.summonerLookup( null, $filter('formatSlug')(el.innerHTML) );

    e.preventDefault();
  };




  return this.init();
}]);
```

Comment: can you provide your controller code?

Comment: do you use ui-router

Comment: Ok, i've added the relevant controller code. @KonstantinKrass i use `ngRoute`... not sure if ui-router is different?